# I don't see urllib.request module in python3. Throws error

Tags: python-3.4, urllib

I don't see urllib.request module in python3. Throws following error. Am I missing something? I want to access urllib.request.urlopen

```
Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 19 2015, 20:38:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
>>>
```

As per below link urllib should have request module.
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request.method.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3 you need to import `urllib.request` instead of `urllib`'

Like this:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> urllib.request.Request
<class 'urllib.request.Request'>
```